# Can we add scroll view onto siri intents/custom UI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sirikit

I just want to check that can we add scroll view onto intentsUI view controller for sirikit to display a scrollable content on siri. Or is there a way about how to add a large content onto siri view.

Please share your thoughts around it. Thanks

Comment: I was trying to add scroll view but i failed and when i increase the desired size of the intent view, the scrolling is enabled.